# List behaviour with duplicate entries

Tags: python, list, for-loop, duplicates

I have a problem concerning duplicate list entries. My data are more complex than the below example, but the idea is the same.

I have a list. Depending on other factors (outside this code), in some cases I need a duplicate of some of the list elements. Having copied them, I then want to give all list elements a unique number. However, I find that the copied elements (the original and the copy) get the same number. How do I solve this problem?

```
list = [["apple", '', "a"], ["pear", '', "b"]] 
list.append(list[0])

counter = 0 
for item in list:  
    counter += 1
    item[1] = counter
```

This yields the list:

```
[['apple', 3, 'a'], ['pear', 2, 'b'], ['apple', 3, 'a']]
```

But what I wanted was:

```
[['apple', 1, 'a'], ['pear', 2, 'b'], ['apple', 3, 'a']]
```

(I can't just append the counter, because it's a specific column that needs to be filled in)

Comment: It's not a copy, you're adding the same list at the end(try: `list[0] is list[-1]`). A simple fix will be to use slicing.

Comment: `list.append(list[0][:])` also don't use list as a variable name